# How to fix runtime error 6124 "You are not allowed to edit this selection because it is protected"

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have this Excel VBA code that could export data into placeholders in Word. But when I modified it to find and replace a placeholder in Word Header, I get the above stated error

Here is the code I've been working with: 
The error happens along this line
".Application.Selection = Worksheets("Details").Range("C22").Value"

```
Sub DespatchPdf()
  Dim wApp As Word.Application, wDoc As Word.Document
  Dim HdTxt As String

  Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  wApp.Visible = True
  HdTxt = Worksheets("Details").Range("C22").Value

  Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open("C:\file.docx")

  'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False

'Copy Range from Excel
  Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Takeda SoW").Range("G213:AJ471")

'Create an Instance of MS Word
  On Error Resume Next

    'Is MS Word already opened?
      Set wApp = GetObject(Class:="Word.Application")

    'Clear the error between errors
      Err.Clear

    'If MS Word is not already open then open MS Word
      If wApp Is Nothing Then Set wApp = CreateObject(Class:="Word.Application")

    'Handle if the Word Application is not found
      If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "Microsoft Word could not be found, aborting."
        GoTo EndRoutine
      End If

  On Error GoTo 0

'Make MS Word Visible and Active
  wApp.Visible = True
  wApp.Activate

'Create a New Document
  'Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add

'Copy Excel Table Range
  tbl.Copy

'Paste Table into MS Word
  wDoc.Bookmarks("BK1").Range.PasteExcelTable _
    LinkedToExcel:=False, _
    WordFormatting:=False, _
    RTF:=False

    With wApp
    '.ActiveWindow.View.ReadingLayout = False
    .ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
    End With

    With wDoc
    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "InsertTitle1"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Worksheets("Details").Range("C22").Value
    .Application.Selection.EndOf


    End With

'Autofit Table so it fits inside Word Document
  Set WordTable = wDoc.Tables(1)
  WordTable.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)

EndRoutine:
'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True

'Clear The Clipboard
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

  wDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:="C:\file.pdf", ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF



End Sub
```

Any help to bypass this error and replace the "InsertTitle1" text in the Header, will be appreciated

Comment: Can happen for lots of reasons. Document is locked, in protected mode, it’s an uneditable region (like the end or beginning of a row). Try wApp.ActiveWindow.View = wdNormalView or wdPrintView. Normal view is generally faster but formatting can sometimes be goofy i.e. looks like the end of a line but it’s actually not. I’m on mobile but when I get in to the office I’ll take a closer look.

Comment: First, please open the document in Word, as a user. Go to the Developer tab, click the "Restrict Editing" button to show that task pane. Is any kind of protection activated? If yes, which? Also, does this problem occur only in one document, or all documents?

Comment: There's no kind of protection activated in the pane. Yet to try other documents

Comment: If you want people to see that you've responded you have to remember to "ping" them @SmithO. otherwise no one will know you've replied.

Comment: When you look at the document, after the error is being shown, what do you see? Where is the selection in Word? Can you use the [edit] link to include a screen shot?